# PowerBI hierarchy creation without the cloud

Tags: excel, hierarchy, powerpivot, powerview, powerbi

Right now we can create hierarchies in PowerPivot but I'm pretty sure I can't do it in PowerBI.  I could create a Data Model in PowerPivot and use that for PowerBI I think.  Is there any other work around that could be more desktop based?

Thanks!
 Mike

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a hierarchy in a PowerBI dashboard.  After creating this, I can do drill downs and some other hierarchy related tasks

Comment: Are you talking about PowerBI Preview? Click on Edit Report and drop one field under another in the axis area. That will allow you to drill through from one level to another.

Comment: Ok that works.  I am using the PowerBI Dashboard designer that is desktop based.  I am still interested in creating hierarchies overall, similar to doing it in PowerPivot in the diagramming model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a hierarchy in the Power BI Dashboard Preview or in Power BI. If you want this feature I would encourage you to add it to the proposed feature list here: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi or vote for the item if it already exists.

You can create hierarchies in Power Pivot and deploy the model to Power BI Preview but the hierarchies are not visible.